# How to upload Text Files from Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How to upload Text Files to Firebase Cloud Storage , from Firebase Cloud Functions ?
I have deployed a http trigger Cloud Function , which retrieves few documents from a Firestore collection and saves them as a JSON object. Now I need to upload a Text File with the above mentioned JSON object as it's content , to Firebase Cloud Storage , using Firebase Cloud Functions.

Comment: I think following the cloud firestore documentation to upload and get he download link of the text file will be a good option. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start hop it helps

Comment: Do you want to add code to existing cloud function? or you want to create new function? how do you want to trigger it?